# Aumentar o disminuir valores en el campo input no funciona al cambiar el orden de los botones

Tags: jquery

En ocasiones me gustaría poder ubicar los botones en diferente orden, de esta manera:

```
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min" />
    <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />

    <input type="button" value="-" class="min" />
    <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />
</div>
```

O de esta forma:

```
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min" />

    <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min" />
</div>
```

Pero el código solo me funciona en este orden:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.min').click(function(){
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).prev(".quantity").val());
        if (currentVal != 1) {
            $(this).prev(".quantity").val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
    $('.plus').click(function(){
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).next(".quantity").val());
        $(this).next(".quantity").val(currentVal + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input type="button" value="+"  class="plus">
    <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity">
    <input type="button" value="-"  class="min">
</div>
```

Que cambios debo a realizar para que funcione en cualquier orden, sin importar la ubicación de los botones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te funciona porque estás utilizando `.next` y `.prev` por tanto, el navegador espera estrictamente que el botón de decremento esté antes del input y el de incrementar esté después.

Una posible solución a tu problema sustituir `.next` y `.prev` por `siblings`. Eso te asegurará de encontrar el + y el - donde quiera que estén. Eso sí, asegúrate de tener solo un `+`, un `-` y un `input` por cada `div`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.min').click(function(){
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).siblings(".quantity").val());
        if (currentVal != 1) {
            $(this).siblings(".quantity").val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
    $('.plus').click(function(){
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).siblings(".quantity").val());
        $(this).siblings(".quantity").val(currentVal + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min" />
     <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity"> 
</div>

<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min" />
</div>

<div class="bsk-quantity">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="min" />
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />
    <input type="text" value="1" class="quantity">
    
</div>
```